# Ender 3 V2 hotend temperature issues

Tags: creality-ender-3, temperature

Recently, I started experimenting with new filaments on my Ender 3 V2. I got a spool from [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VKSW6PS).

This is PETG filament and I started dialing in the temperature to run a smooth print. I found on my V2, if I run the filament around 240 °C, it prints very smoothly and the extruder doesn't jitter or distort the filament during printing.

However, I found after the printer was printing for about an hour it had reduced its hotend temperature to 210 °C and the print went bad! I have a stock hotend for the V2. Any thoughts as to why the temperature would have reduced itself?

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE. The printer does not change the temperature without a corresponding instruction. Check if your G-code contains temperature reduction instructions. Did you have similar problems with a previous print? Is this the first time you are printing with PETG? Are the settings in your slicer correctly set?

Comment: IMHO the answer for this question is found [here](/a/11811/5740), and as such a duplicate, please find out if your printer has [Thermal Protection](/q/8466/) enabled, read for details [this answer](/a/8467/).